# Persistent Google Sign In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-signin

I managed to set up google sign-in into my app and it works fine. I also added a log-out button that works. The problem I face is that whenever I open the app, it requires the user to log into **google** (or just press the button) before moving on to the next `activity`. I have tried many different ways to solve this, but none seem to work. Can someone help me make a persistent **google** sign-in, in which even if the user closes the app, it keeps them logged in, and they never see the login activity (unless if they sign out)?

Here is my code to my `LoginActivity`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    SignInButton signInButton;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private int progress;
    private int SIGN_IN;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();

            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            progress = prefs.getInt("SIGN_IN", 0);
            signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signInWithGoogle);
            signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = prefs.edit();
                    editPrefs.putInt("SIGN_IN", 1);
                    editPrefs.apply();
                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            if (result.isSuccess()){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentInformationFormActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem once, I looked at my old code and saw such thing:

```
   @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleSignInAccount lastSignedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (lastSignedInAccount != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

So you can check if user is logged in Actovity's onStart and if so, move to the next activity. Hope helps :)